# How to remove data local storage in specific index or row

Tags: javascript

in my code, if I run, my data in local storage remove all. how I can delete 1 row where I choice
I confuse how to delete row in table data from local storage

my problem now is, when i click button delete in row table, row choice removed but data in local storage not remove and then when i refresh page, data show again.

```
function hapus(r){
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
  localStorage.removeItem('dataProduk');
}
```

Full Code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
    $('#getProduks').change(function(e){
      let data = $('#getProduks').val();
      let datas = data.split('|');
      let idProduk = datas[0];
      let hargaProduk = datas[1];
      let stokProduk = datas[2];
      let namaProduk = datas[3];

      $('#hargaProduk').val('');
      $('#hargaProduk').val(hargaProduk);
    })

    let dataStore = localStorage.getItem('dataProduk') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataProduk')) : [];
    let subAllTotal = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < dataStore.length; i++){

      let table = `
      <tr>
        <td width="10" align="center" scope="row"></td>
        <td><button type="submit" onclick="hapus(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
        <td>&nbsp;${dataStore[i].namaProduk}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;${dataStore[i].hargaProduk}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;${dataStore[i].disProduk}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;${dataStore[i].jumProduk}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;${(dataStore[i].hargaProduk * dataStore[i].jumProduk) - (dataStore[i].hargaProduk * dataStore[i].jumProduk * dataStore[i].disProduk/100)}</td>          
      </tr>
      `

      $('tbody').append(table);        

      subAllTotal += (dataStore[i].hargaProduk * dataStore[i].jumProduk) - (dataStore[i].hargaProduk * dataStore[i].jumProduk * dataStore[i].disProduk/100)
    }

    $('#subAllTotal').html(jadiinRupiah(subAllTotal));


    $('#tambahProduk').click(function(){

        let namaP = $('#getProduks').val().split('|')[3];
        let hargaP = $('#hargaProduk').val();
        let disP = $('#getDis').val();
        let jumP = $('#getJum').val();

        let data = {
          namaProduk: namaP,
          hargaProduk: hargaP,
          disProduk: disP,
          jumProduk: jumP
        }

        dataStore.push(data)
        localStorage.setItem('dataProduk',JSON.stringify(dataStore))
        let subAllTotal = 0;

        let table = `
        <tr>
          <td width="10" align="center" scope="row"></td>
          <td><button type="submit" onclick="hapus(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
          <td>&nbsp;${data.namaProduk}</td>
          <td>&nbsp;${data.hargaProduk}</td>
          <td>&nbsp;${data.disProduk}</td>
          <td>&nbsp;${data.jumProduk}</td>
          <td>&nbsp;${(data.hargaProduk * data.jumProduk) - (data.hargaProduk * data.jumProduk * data.disProduk/100)}</td>
        </tr>
        `
        $('tbody').append(table);

        for (var i = 0; i < dataStore.length; i++){
          //subAllTotal += (data.hargaProduk * data.jumProduk) - (data.hargaProduk * data.jumProduk * data.disProduk/100)
          subAllTotal += (dataStore[i].hargaProduk * dataStore[i].jumProduk) - (dataStore[i].hargaProduk * dataStore[i].jumProduk * dataStore[i].disProduk/100)
        }

        $('#subAllTotal').html(jadiinRupiah(subAllTotal));
    })

  });      

  $('#hapusProduk').click(function(){
    localStorage.clear();
  });

function hapus(r){
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
  localStorage.removeItem('dataProduk');
}

function jadiinRupiah(total) {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'IDR'}).format(total).split('IDR')[1].trim()      
}
```

Comment: If `dataProduk` has the same rows as your html table, you can find the items index in the localStorage entry, and set a new value to the localStorage entry with a spliced out item.

Comment: yes i know about index, but i confuse how code work. thanks your respons

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the current array, remove the row and save it again.

```
function hapus(r){
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
  let data = localStorage.getItem('dataProduk');
  data.splice(i,1); //remove data[i]
  localStorage.setItem('dataProduk', data);
}
```

I'm not sure what `dataProduk` looks like - if it's an array the above solution will work but if it's an object you'll have to use `dataProduk.filter`

Comment: hai, thanks your respons.
full code i edit. please check in post